# What is the best way to group this js array items in this structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

how can i convert returned data from this structure:

```
[
    {
      "id": 91,
      "name": "Art",
      "division": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "1st level",
        "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
      },
      "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
    },
    {
      "id": 188,
      "name": "English",
      "division": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "3rd level",
        "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
      },
      "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
    },
    {
      "id": 218,
      "name": "Art",
      "division": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "3rd level",
        "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
      },
      "created_at": "2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00",
    }
  ]
```

to this structure :

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Art",
      "classes": [
       {
        "id": 91,
        "name": "1st level",
       },
       {
        "id": 218,
        "name": "3rd level",
       },
      ],
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "English",
      "classes": [ 
       {
        "id": 188,
        "name": "3rd level",
       },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

**note:** class.id = parentSubject.id

I wrote some codes to solve the problem but I'm looking for the best way !! 
i use .reduce() function 
I will attach the codes in the comments box.

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Comment: *I will attach the codes in the comments box.* Please don't do this, instead please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67942376/edit) to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
let ans = initialArray.reduce((cum,x) => {
  let foundIndex = cum.findIndex((a) =>{
    return a.name == x.name});
   if(foundIndex!=-1){
     cum[foundIndex].classes.push({
       id : x.id,
       name : x.division.name
     })
   }
  else{
    cum.push({
      id : cum.length+1,
      name : x.name,
      classes : [{
       id : x.id,
       name : x.division.name
     }]
    })
  }
  return cum;
},[]);
```

I use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map to create a new array of objects with the new id.

```
const oldDatas = [
  {
    id: 91,
    name: 'Art',
    division: {
      id: 4,
      name: '1st level',
      created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
    },
    created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
  },
  {
    id: 188,
    name: 'English',
    division: {
      id: 9,
      name: '3rd level',
      created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
    },
    created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
  },
  {
    id: 218,
    name: 'Art',
    division: {
      id: 11,
      name: '3rd level',
      created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
    },
    created_at: '2018-11-05T10:11:37+00:00',
  },
];

const newDatas = oldDatas.map((data, index) => {
  return { ...data, id: index + 1 };
});
console.log(newDatas);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output they asked for, it just changes the `id`, it does not merge.

Answer (score 0):

my solution :

```js
  let res = initialArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const exist = acc.findIndex((item) => item.name === obj.name);
    if (exist >= 0) {
      acc[exist] = {
        id: exist,
        name: obj.name,
        classes: [
          ...acc[exist].classes,
          { id: obj.id, name: obj.division.name },
        ],
      };
    } else {
      acc.push({
        id: acc.length,
        name: obj.name,
        classes: [{ id: obj.id, name: obj.division.name }],
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```